# interpret Wilkinson Notation linear regression model matlab

Tags: matlab, model, regression, interpretation

I fitted the following model to my data.

```
Linear regression model:
    NNSB ~ 1 + Gender + Age*MMRC

Estimated Coefficients:
                       Estimate     SE          tStat       pValue    
    (Intercept)           1.8004       1.027      1.7531      0.079978
    Age                 0.014051     0.01529     0.91898       0.35839
    Gender_Male          0.43134    0.099535      4.3335    1.6559e-05
    MMRC_MMRC 1         -0.64548      1.2465    -0.51785       0.60471
    MMRC_MMRC 2           2.5536      1.2689      2.0124      0.044513
    MMRC_MMRC 3           2.1066      1.3638      1.5447       0.12283
    MMRC_MMRC 4             2.07      1.5724      1.3164       0.18841
    Age:MMRC_MMRC 1     0.012023    0.018482     0.65052       0.51555
    Age:MMRC_MMRC 2    -0.034328    0.018843     -1.8218       0.06886
    Age:MMRC_MMRC 3    -0.026653    0.020307     -1.3125       0.18973
    Age:MMRC_MMRC 4    -0.016567    0.023175    -0.71488       0.47489
```

Could you help me in understanding the meaning of the last 4 coefficients?
How should I read the ":" simbol?

MMRC is a categorical variable that can assume the values 0, 1, 2,3 and 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab uses what I think is called *Wilkinson notation* for defining models. This is where the tilde (~) sign comes from too.

When you have a *a*b* term in your model, Matlab actually also includes any lower order terms. For example: *y ~ a*b* in Wilkinson notation actually corresponds to *y = a + b + a*b* in standard notation. If you just want a product in Wilkinson notation without any lower order terms (aka an 'interaction'), this is expressed as *a:b*. So, *y ~ a*b* is equivalent to *y ~ a + b + a:b*.

In your case, the first four MMRC terms correspond to the MMRC's on their own. The final four terms are the interactions between Age and MMRC.

Comment: What you are saying is that my model is: NNSB ~ 1 + Gender + Age + MMRC + Age:MMRC?

Comment: should I take the interaction Age:MMRC as AgexMMRC?

Comment: Yes, your model corresponds to _NNSB ~ 1 + Gender + Age + MMRC + Age:MMRC_, and _Age:MMRC_ in Wilkinson notation corresponds to _Age x MMRC_ in 'standard' notation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since I have only 1 term with p < 0.05 (MMRC_MMRC 2) Can I assume that it is the only factor that affects the response variable? In particular, if a subject is MMRC2 he has +2 unit of NNSB with respect to a subject belonging to the other MMRC classes (assuming all the rest equal)

Comment: Gender has a p-value (much lower than) 0.05

Comment: Yes! I didn't see it! So can I conclude that gender is the main factor that affect NNSB and then MMRC_MMRC2?

Comment: What the p-values are saying is that it is highly unlikely that gender has no influence on NNSB, and pretty unlikely that MMRC_MMRC2 has no influence on NNSB, but they do not say anything about how large an effect these variables have. The coefficient estimates indicate that MMRC_MMRC2 has a larger effect than gender, even when you take the standard errors into account. I should mention though that I am not a statistician and these conclusions should probably be accompanied by a plethora of caveats.

Comment: Say that the output is     NNSB ~ 1 + Age*Gender + Age*MMRC, how would you convert it? Should I include the Age term twice? 
NNSB ~ 1 + Age + Gender + Age:Gender + Age + MMRC + Age:MMRC